# Get GDBusConnection for Bus name that's already owned

Tags: glib, dbus, vala, gdbus

I would like to register an object for a Bus name that's already owned. Below is how I would register an object on a new Bus, but `own_name` fails if the Bus already exists. Can I retrieve the DBusConnection object some other way so I can call `register_object`?

```
Bus.own_name (BusType.SESSION, "net.launchpad.Diodon", BusNameOwnerFlags.NONE,
    conn => {
        try {
            conn.register_object ("/net/launchpad/Diodon", new DBusController (controller));
        } catch (IOError e) {
            stderr.printf ("Could not register service\n");
        }
    },
    () => {},
    () => stderr.printf ("Could not aquire name\n"));
```

Comment: Names can only be owned by one program at a time ... do you have any wider context on what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

As described on [Gio docs](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.BusNameOwnerFlags.html#!), if the bus name was owned by a message bus connection using `BusNameOwnerFlags.ALLOW_REPLACEMENT` you could use `BusNameOwnerFlags.REPLACE` and take the name from the other connection. Otherwise, the `own_name` function will fail to acquire the name.

By the commits I could find on [Diodon git history](https://code.launchpad.net/diodon), it seems `"net.launchpad.Diodon"` was acquired using flag `NONE`.